# For App Extensions in iOS 8, must I use an embedded Framework to share code?

Tags: ios, ios7, app-store, ios8, xcode6

In the "App Extension Programming Guide" it states "You can create an embedded framework to share code between your app extension and its containing app."

Since I have to support iOS 7 too and I have shared code between both, can I still opt to statically compile my code for both the extension and containing app separately? Will the app get rejected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you can statically compile your code for both the app and the extension and it will be approved by Apple.

I know because my app was approved :)